# What does the number of channels mean in pyaudio?

Tags: python, pyaudio

From all the different questions that I referred to, I observed that people usually use the following configuration for pyaudio:

```
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5 #depends how much you want to record.
```

With this configuration, the size of the recorded file (let's say `sample.wav`) will be `41000(RATE) * 4(sizeofeachsample) *5 (duration) = 0.882 Kb`, and if we use `Channel=1`, then the size will be half of it and accordingly for other values. Can someone tell me what `CHANNEL` really means and what other changes will it have if we use different values?

What is the difference if we use `` CHANNEL=1` or `2` or `3`...? ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Channel refers to the number of audio streams to use. Many modern computer speaker setups and audio files will have two channels for stereo output, one for the left speaker and the right speaker.

Note that buffers will usually interleave the data of different channels. That is, if one channel has the following data:

[0,1,2,3,4,5]

and another has:

[9,10,11,12,13,14]

Then the buffer will contain:
[0,9,1,10,2,11,3,12,4,13,5,14]

Comment: If you are saying Channel refers to the number of audio streams then why does it reduces the size of the file to half if i use CHANNEL=1 instead of 2? Ultimately both the channels are combined and if there is only one channel then it should still have the same size right? @0x534f53

Comment: No. If there's two channels, theres twice the amount of data. Notice how in my example the combined buffer is twice as long as either of the single channel data.

Comment: I see. But then does it mean more the number of channels, more information the data will have? Better quality? And what is the actual difference if I use 1 channel or 2?

Comment: No, the channels just represent the number of different streams. Things like the bitrate are still the same for each channel. If you have a mono-output audio file, expanding it to two channels won't add any meaningful or beneficial change. On the other hand, if you were to change a stereo audio into one channel, you would have to either choose one stream over the other (i.e. only hear the left or right speaker) or average out the values of the two channels. So in that case you would lose some of the original data

Comment: My end goal is to collect sample and use Google speech to text. How many number of channels would you suggest me to use?

Comment: Haven't used google speech to text, but one channel should work best. I don't imagine having stereo audio or even more channels helping with google's speech recognition algorithm.